# Problema al descargar archivo PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf

[image: Error al descargar]

hola buen día espero puedan apoyarme con este error al querer descargar el archivo a pdf no me deja, cabe recalcar que puedo visualizarlo, pero no descargarlo. dejo el pequeño codigo que tengo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
El código, los errores y todo lo relacionado debe ir, hasta donde se pueda, como texto. Poner imágenes se lo hace difícil a los que intentan replicar tu problema, a los que ven esto desde un móvil o a los que tienen discapacidad visual en algún grado. Nadie te va a responder con imágenes.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Revisa la consola del navegador y el log de errores de PHP; trae esa info a tu pregunta. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta)

Comment: Revisa la [documentación](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_Output) de tcpdf sobre las opciones de Output()

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas la [documentación](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) de fpdf sobre el cual esta basada la librería TCPDF que estas usando puedes ver las opciones para el Output de la última linea del codigo, para la descarga del archivo PDF debe quedar asi:

```
$pdf->Output($_POST['fileNamePrintReportes'].'.pdf',"F");
```

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, pero diria que te has confundido poniendo un punto (de concatenación de caracteres en PHP) en lugar de una coma antes del parámetro F.

Comment: Aparte de eso, tcpdf tiene su propia [documentación](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/TCPDF/classes-TCPDF/#method_Output) al respecto sobre Output() donde lo más destacable es el cambio de orden de los parámetros